# Woo-commerce product filter is not displaying using shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently i am trying to display woo-commerce product filter using short-code `[woocommerce_product_filter]`  but it's nothing display only showing text of short-code.

I have used same short-code in admin page and my custom template.

Custom template display short code.

```
<?php  echo do_shortcode("[woocommerce_product_filter]");   ?>
```

I got reference link for display product filter from [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/shortcodes/woocommerce_product_filter/)

Can anyone suggest me how can i display product filter of woo-commerce in my custom template.

Comment: There is a typo in your shortcode - you have a single quote before your closing bracket `[woocommerce_product_filter']`should be `[woocommerce_product_filter]` :)

Comment: I have set but still not working

Comment: I am certain you don't actually need __any__ single quotes there. Try `<?php  echo do_shortcode("[woocommerce_product_filter]");   ?> ` instead?

Comment: I removed single quote but still not working only display nothing

Comment: What happens if you remove the `echo` command?

Comment: @PavelJanicek , Once i removed echo display nothing.

Comment: which file you added the code?

Comment: @silver , I used short-code in my custom template of my custom plugin

Comment: @SamirSheikh Do you have installed and activated "WooCommerce Product Search"  WooCommerce Extensions plugin? Since "[woocommerce_product_filter]"  shortcode is supported in the WooCommerce Product Search Extensions plugin.